# Memory for deployed App in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, memory, deployment, settings

I need to bring some light to my question. The question is : is there any way to influence how much heap memory Tomcat allocates for particular deployed application ? In more details - how can I set specific java options for deployed application (consider I want to have special GC settins, special mem-ration settings and so on and so forth per Application) ?

P.S.: One more question - where can I find information about how Application Servers execute deployed applications and how they do memory management ? Tried to look through but had no success (only common info available - such as dev guide, user guide, admin guide, but non of there contain info I do demand).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Heap Memory **can't** be set for any specific application in Tomcat.

Comment: But if my app demands 30GB RAM ( for example ) does it mean that I got to set not less then 30GB for a Tomcat instance as well ?

Comment: I think either I'm not clear in your query or you are getting me wrong. You cannot set heap mem for a particular app in Tomcat. As for your this query goes, The heap memory should be set depending on your app requirement. If your App requires **30GB** than you've to set it above that.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure heap space as given here.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/setting-tomcat-heap-size-jvm-heap-eclipse/